# Can union types in typescript 1.4 be used to declare d3-style "chained" getter/setters?

Tags: typescript

A common pattern in libraries like [D3](http://d3js.org) is "stackable getter/setters".

For example (from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)):

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);
```

Here, `charge`, `linkDistance` and `size` are used as setters that each return an instance of the force object so that they can be "chained".

However, they may be also used as getters by not specifying a parameter, e.g.:

```
var d = force.linkDistance()
```

If called after the first code block, the value of `d` will now be `30`.

I would like to use typescript 1.4's new union-type feature to create such chainable getter/setters.  For example, the following compiles to the correct javascript:

```
class O {
    private _a: number = 0;
    a(x: number = null): O|number {
        if (x) {
            this._a = x;
            return this;
        }
        return this._a;
    }
}
```

such that from javascript I can do:

```
var o = new O();
var v = o.a(3).a();
```

now v = 3.

but from typescript, I need to cast:

```
var o = new O();
var v: number = <number>(<O>o.a(3)).a();
```

not very appealing!

interestingly, looking at [d3.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts), it seems people have been creating interfaces with the correct signature like so:

```
interface IA {
    a: {
        (): number;
        (x: number): IA;
    }
}
```

This somehow magically resolves to the right signatures to wrap javascript, but I have no idea how to implement such an interface in typescript!

So my question is, is it possible to code such chainable getters/setters without requiring casts when they are used called in typescript?  Alternately, is it possible to create a typescript class that implements the interface `IA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to code such chainable getters/setters without requiring casts when they are used called in typescript? Alternately, is it possible to create a typescript class that implements the interface IA

Yes. Using function overloads:

```
interface IA {
    a: {
        (): number;
        (x: number): IA;
    }
}

class A implements IA {
    private _a;
    a(): number
    a(x: number): A
    a(x?: any): any {
        if (x == void 0){
            return this._a;
        }
        else {
            this._a = x;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

var foo = new A(); 
var bar = foo.a(123); // okay
console.log(bar.a()); // 123
foo.a('not a number'); // Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning the union type you actually create new type `O|number`

```
var o2: O|number = o.a(3);
```

There is no way TypeScript compiler can understand what exact type do you need without casting.

Actually union types were introduced mostly to remove function overloads and they could be used (at least for now) with type casting/checking only.

For you example the only way I can see is to use 2 different methods to set and get value:

```
class O {
    private _a: number = 0;

    setA(x: number): O {        
        this._a = x;
        return this;
    }

    getA(): number {
        return this._a; 
    }
}

var o: O = new O();
var v: number = o.setA(3).getA();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this would be the answer.  In normal circumstances this would probably be OK.  Unfortunately, I'm trying to build a D3 plugin and hence follow the pattern.  Is it also impossible in typescript then to implement an interface like IA (and those in D3.d.ts)?

Comment: `There is no way TypeScript compiler can understand what exact type do you need without casting.`. Wrong. You can use function overloads

Comment: @MaxBrodin - when using union types you can use type guards to avoid most casts (although function overloads are the correct solution here).